# Craft 3: query matrixBlocks and eager load its owner?

Tags: craft3, eager-loading

Does anybody know if it's possible to load matrixBlock and eager load the entries (=owner) the matrixBlocks belong to in Craft 3?

I tried:

```
{% set blocks = craft.matrixBlocks.type('eventDate').fieldId(4).with('owner') %}
```

but this does not work. Leaving out the `.with('owner')` works perfectly and then access its owner by `block.owner.<fieldname>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently no, but I suppose since Craft 3 added the `craft.matrixBlocks()` template function, it would make sense to make this possible.

Just created a FR about this: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1820